# Cannot mount remote NFS share to NFS client

Tags: nfs

On NFS Server (CentOS):

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat /etc/exports

/IT_Projects 192.168.56.0/25(ro,root_squash)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:C4:A8:B6  
          inet addr:192.168.56.101  Bcast:192.168.56.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fec4:a8b6/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1790 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:230 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:252381 (246.4 KiB)  TX bytes:27381 (26.7 KiB)
```

On NFS Client (CentOS):

```
 eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:C4:A8:B6  
              inet addr:192.168.56.102  Bcast:192.168.56.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
              inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fec4:a8b6/64 Scope:Link
              UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
              RX packets:1609 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:145 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
              RX bytes:231539 (226.1 KiB)  TX bytes:11555 (11.2 KiB)


[root@localhost ~]# mount -t nfs4 192.168.56.101:/IT_Projects /mnt/proj
```

results in connection timeout.

```
[root@localhost ~]# dmesg | tail
sf_read_super_aux err=-71
sf_read_super_aux err=-71
sf_read_super_aux err=-71
fuse init (API version 7.16)
FS-Cache: Loaded
FS-Cache: Netfs 'nfs' registered for caching
EXT3-fs (sdc2): error: no journal found. mounting ext3 over ext2?
Installing knfsd (copyright (C) 1996 okir@monad.swb.de).
NFSD: Using /var/lib/nfs/v4recovery as the NFSv4 state recovery directory
NFSD: starting 90-second grace period

[root@localhost ~]# ping 192.168.56.102
PING 192.168.56.102 (192.168.56.102) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.56.102: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.422 ms
```

Can ping the client from the server.

I have turned SELinux off, and started the rpcbind, nfs, daemons on both NFS client and server. I also changed Defvers=3 in /etc/nfsmount.conf on the Server to no effect. What other avenues can I explore to fix the problem?

```
    [root@localhost ~]# rpcinfo -p 192.168.56.101
rpcinfo: can't contact portmapper: RPC: Remote system error - No route to host

[root@localhost IT_Projects]# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ssh 
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: Can the server itself mount the filesystem via NFS?

Comment: What does `rpcinfo -p server_ip_address` on the client show?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick do you mean can the server act as both client and server? If so yes, `mount -t nfs4 192.168.56.101:/IT_Projects /mnt/IT_Projects` works.

Received this error on client: `rpcinfo: can't contact portmapper: RPC: Remote system error - No route to host`

Comment: Also, `rpcinfo -p 192.168.56.101` and `rpcinfo -p 192.168.56.102` gives output when executed on the server.

Comment: Added the output above @MarkPlotnick. `nmap -Pn 192.168.56.101` on the client only shows port 22 as open.

Comment: What does the firewall config look like on the server?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick posted above. Sorry I don't really understand the output properly.

Comment: You have the default firewall settings, which only allow incoming ssh. Do you feel comfortable using the `iptables` or `system-config-firewall` or `firewall-config` commands to open the NFS and rpc (and mountd, lockd, and statd if you're using NFSv3) ports?

Comment: Apologies @MarkPlotnick I assumed that INPUT ALL would allow all incoming connections. Unfortunately I am not familiar with iptables, can I instead configure hosts.allow/.deny?
If not I will have a go at configuring via iptables. Thanks

Comment: `iptables -L` unfortunately doesn't show the interfaces that the rule applies to. `iptables -L -v` will. The second `ACCEPT all -- anywhere anywhere` rule you have may actually be `ACCEPT all -- lo any anywhere anywhere`, meaning it only applies to input from the loopback interface.

Comment: Using hosts.allow and hosts.deny for NFS may work, according to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNFSHowTo but I have not tried it.

Comment: Alright thanks @MarkPlotnick, for now I will use the graphical tool and see if I can translate that understanding to iptables. Cheers for the extensive help.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick would you like to write up an answer? So I can select your answer as the correct answer?

Comment: Working on it... need to research how to set up NFSv4.

Comment: check my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26187345/iptables-rules-for-nfs-server-and-nfs-client